# Get an iteratable JSON from view in template without unicode values

Tags: python, json, django

I have created a python (2.7) dictionary with the following structure:

```
cntr_rgns = {'country_1':[region1, region2, region3], 'country_2':[region1, region2] ..}
```

I pass it to my contextdioctionary as:

```
ctx['regions'] = cntr_rgns
```

What I want is to display the values in my template.

In my template view I did that:

```
{% if regions %}
    {% for region in regions.items %}
        <option value={{ region }}>{{ region }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But I again get the unicode values:

(u'Canada',[u'somethong',u'something else',u..])

How can I get back an iteratable JSON or something?

Comment: How do you expect the output to be? and do you want to list all the regions of all counties or a specific country?

Comment: I want the output to be without the unicode characters. As: (Canada,[region,region else,...]) I will pass all the countries with the regions in the context dictionary and then I will filter them there based on the value that the user selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want JSON, you need to actually create some JSON.

```
 ctx['regions'] = json.dumps(cntr_rgns)
```

Comment: The issue is that when I do this then in my returned JSON string I get lots of escaped values.